# Construct and pass JavaScript string list to ASP.NET MVC Controller action (not using ajax)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

How do I construct a list of strings in JavaScript and pass it to `window.location` such that it will show up as `List<string>` on the C# side of the fence?
(Not using Ajax POST, but instead using `window.location`)

Example ASP.NET MVC Controller action:

```
public FileResult GetMyCsvFile(List<string> columnNames)
{
  ...
}
```

Example JavaScript:

```
$('export-button').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // TODO: How do I construct the next line(s) such that it can pass a list of strings to my C# controller action?
    window.location = ROOT_PATH + "Home/GetMyCsvFile ... ????
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
"Home/GetMyCsvFile?columnNames=firstColumn&columnNames=secondColumn...."
```

As an example, create the `<a>` tag and give it an id

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Click me", "Test", "Task", null, new { id = "myLink" })
```

then in the script (note I've used jquery since that's what you used in the question)

```
$('#myLink').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Define the values to pass to the controller
  var firstCol = 'value1';
  var secondCol = 'value2';
  // Construct url with query string
  var path = $(this).attr('href');
  path += '?columnNames=' + firstCol + '&columnNames=' + secondCol;
  // Navigate to the view
  window.location = path;
});
```

If its a variable list of values, you would need to construct the url in a loop, something like

```
for (var i = 0; i < myValues.length; i++) {
  if (i === 0) {
    path += '?columnNames=' + myValues[i];
  } else {
    path += '&columnNames=' + myValues[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea. Could you show the JavaScript code on how to _construct_ that query string? Thanks!

Comment: OK, that could work and it's straight-forward. I wasn't sure if there was a clever way in JS of taking `myValues` and projecting it to a querystring (other than building the string via a loop). Thanks again.  I'll mark this as the answer... unless a better idea comes along. :)